# Custom Session State Store for .Net 2.0 performance issue

Tags: asp.net, performance, postgresql, session-state

I developed a custom session state store for .Net 2.0 using PostgresSql (driver is Npgsql). The custom store run well but we face with a serious problem: PERFOMANCE.
If not using custom state, in rush hour, CPU utilization is only 10% but with the custom store, CPU utilization is about 100%. We change to use free version of Devart for Postgres, the problem is the same.
There are about 2000 request per second to our webservice from about 1000 sessions (one person can open several browser tab using our webpage). Each session store only a bool, a string and an integer in Session at session created time only.
I am using stored procedure in Postgres to interact with DB.
If I change the config file to remove custom session, the problem is solved :((
Any one using custom session store face with performance problem?
Is there any performance problem in Npgsql (I am using the latest)?
Please help!

**UPDATE 1**
We change to use DB as Oracle 10g using free dotconnect from devart, the problem is the same.
**UPDATE 2**
w3sp.exe process is a greatest CPU consumer (90%)

Comment: Sorry, I can not post the code here. In custom session store, there is no loop. So that I think the problem originate from M$ Session store provider mechanism.

Comment: There's no sign that your issue has anything to do with nPgSQL. You need to be doing some analysis to determine what's bottlenecking the system. What happens to the query rate when you turn the session provider on/off? Which queries is running most often, and which are taking the most time? Check out `pg_stat_statements`, which will be helpful for this. Can you interpose a caching layer, store session data in non-durable unlogged table, etc?

Comment: I think the problem not reside in DB but HttpModule its self

Answer (score 1):

Now I am sure that custom session storage using DB consume a lot of CPU if there too many request per second.
We are using: CPU X3210, Main Intel S3000AH, Windows 2003 R2. There 2000 requests per second.